# nginx subdomain to directory , too many redirect , why?

Tags: nginx, subdomain

this is my config:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name ~^(?<sb>.+)\.a\.b\.c\.com$;
    access_log  /data/logs/nginx/tas.access.log  main;
    location / {
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        proxy_pass http://b.c/a/$sb/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

and browser report to many redirects.

Comment: Where does `proxy_pass http://b.c/a/$sb/;` point to. It seems a bit odd.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by the way?

Comment: it's a upstream ,  localhost:8082

Comment: So if I understand correctly the upstream redirects back to `*.a.b.c.com`?

Comment: Maybe your upstream config is wrong. Read http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUpstreamModule for more insight

Answer (score 0):

If, as you say, you want to proxy to localhost:8082, you need to say so in the proxy_pass line:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^(?<sb>.+)\.a\.b\.c\.com$;
    access_log /data/logs/nginx/tas.access.log main;
    location / {
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8082/a/$sb/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without all of the information, it's hard to guess what's going on. Based on the comments, my guess is that you are using virtual hosting so that the upstream site is also served by the same nginx. So this line is the problem:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

The nginx variable $host is pointing to the current Host header (which matches the server_name). So if you set the same host header for the upstream again, then nginx will find the same location block above because nginx relies on the Host header to find the proper server. Thus the redirect loop.

Set

```
proxy_set_header Host your_upstream_server_name
```

will fix it then.